# Is there a way to merge projects in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a solution with 3 C++ projects to create .dlls for an application. Recently in a meeting we decided we would merge the 3 projects and have them in a single project instead as having the 3 projects would not materially improve our ability to manage the code. Is there a way to do this without copy/pasting a bunch of files? To be honest we don't have that much code so I may do that at some point, but wanted to learn if there would be a "proper" way. We use Visual studio 2017. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cut/paste is simplest the way to go, so no doubt Microsoft designs no other way.

Comment: So do you want to turn those 3 DLL's into 1 DLL? If so, choose the project that'll produce the DLL, and then just add the .CPP files from the other projects to that one.